# how to exclude an arbitrary period of time (1-2 hours) from the PHP array

Tags: php

There is an array of working hours, how to exclude lunch time from it?

```
$start = strtotime('8:00');
$end = strtotime('18:00');
$step = 1800; // 30 min

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step)
{
    $arTime[] = date('H:i', $i);
}

print_r($arTime);
```

Comment: show us what you have tried, your best attempt

Comment: for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step)
{
 if($i != strtotime('13:00') and $i != strtotime('14:00'))
 {
  $arTime[] = date('H:i', $i);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

A class that allows easy creation / manipulation / comparison of date and time, you can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to create the desired array.

Set a time-interval that is to be excluded from your results array using `$lunchStart` and `$lunchStop`.

```
$start = new DateTime('8:00');
$end = new DateTime('18:00');
$lunchStart = new DateTime('13:00');
$lunchStop = new DateTime('14:00');

while ($start <= $end) {
    $slot = $start->format('H:i');
    if ($start <= $lunchStart || $start >= $lunchStop) {
        $arTime[] = $slot;
    }
    $start->add(new DateInterval('PT30M')); // 30 min interval
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/uNQC3)